# Android ScaleAnimation is relative to current size not acctual size... how to fix?

Tags: android, animation

I have a button which makes another object scale-up in size when pressed.

Both objects are added to the view in code with

```
container.addView(button)
container.addView(object)
object.scaleX = 0f;
object.scaleY = 0f;
```

Later I want to animation scale from 0f to 1f... like so:

```
      val scaleAnimation = ScaleAnimation(0f, 1f,
      0f, 1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,
      0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.5f)
      scaleAnimation.fillAfter = true
      scaleAnimation.duration = 100
      object.startAnimation(scaleAnimation)
```

This doesn't work. In ScaleAnimation 0f and 1f are relative to the objects current scale, rather than to it's actual size. Surely, this should not be the case?

If I replace the animation with just object.scaleX = 1f... it works no matter the original scaleX. So, it seems like ScaleAnimation doesn't actually animate the ScaleX and ScaleY properties of the object, it just adds a new layer of scale on top.

How can I make the animation work on the actual ScaleX property of the object, with the object starting at 0f and then animating up to 1f when it needs to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out ScaleAnimation isn't the right animator for this. In the end I found out I had to use:

```
object.animate().scaleX(1f).scaleY(1f).setDuration(100).setInterpolator(DecelerateInterpolator())
```

This method actually animates the actual ScaleX and Y properties of the object, rather than define some new scale layer on top.